# Customize appearance of digital signature in Okular

Tags: linux, pdf, okular

I am using **KDE Neon**, and I have successfully configured Okular to add a digital signature to my PDF (using Tools > Digitally Sign menuitem).

However, it looks ugly like this (the rectangle with black border and light grey fill):

[image]

(I added some black rectangles to censor some sensitive info)

Is there a way to customize this ugly representation of the digital signature? I figure to have only the "Signed by:" line and "Date:" line, both left-aligned, will be enough.

Comment: Had similar issue on okular, just opened an issue: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=477108